# How do people make Tex documents?

Tags: pdftex

What do you all use to make Tex documents is there a compiler or something?
How do I make a Tex document and then print it.

For some reason I have a nagging feeling that the commands don't work like they work on stackexchange.

Comment: we install MikTeX or TeXLive distros and use an editor that is capable of calling TeX.

Comment: You're confusing the instructions in Math.SE or Physics.SE with TeX, but it isn't TeX, it's MathJaX only, having roughly the same syntax. For real documents we use a normal editor, type in the instruction and use a compiler.

Comment: The most important step is to read a introduction to LaTeX. After installing texlive, MikTeX you can get the documentation of a package by typing »texdoc packagename« on the command line.